# cordova-plugin-datecs-printer : Printing non-latin characters

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, escpos

I have an Ionic app with cordova-plugin-datecs printer installed. It works fine unless I try to print non-latin characters (ă, â, ț, 大, 埔, 區, etc.). It prints weird symbols for these. I'm sure that the printer supports these characters because I've printed them with another app.

This is the printing function:

```
 public printText(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      DatecsPrinter.printText('埔區埔區埔區', 'UTF-8', success => {
          resolve(success);
      }, function (error) {
          reject(error);
      });
    });
 }
```